# I am creating a maven project, and thecontent of a MANIFEST.MF does not react to changes in the pom.xml. Where should I look for a mistake?

Tags: eclipse, maven, manifest, pom.xml, executable-jar

I am creating a maven project, and I am editing the pom.xml to specify the main class, etc. The MANIFEST.MF does not change its content, but I am sure I am writing the appropriate lines in the pom.xml. Is it possible the there is a problem in the settings in Eclipse? (I am doing it in Eclipse, btw)  Where should I look for a mistake?

Comment: Please show your pom file? You should check first on plain command line...

Comment: In addition to @khmarbaise's remarks be sure that you check the actual content of the jar file. Extract it using `jar xf target/yourArtifact-yourVersion.jar`. This is because the jar/war plugins compose the manifest while constructing the jar/war file. It is not normally visible immediately after the artefact is built.

Comment: @khmarbaise  please take a look at the pom file: https://codeshare.io/aJ7L8y

Comment: @SteveC this is the content of the jar file: https://codeshare.io/5Q8Pzq

Comment: I don't believe you. This is a listing of your source files. Besides, what we're interested in is the content of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` from the jar file.

Comment: @SteveC which part don't you believe? besides, here is the content of the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:  

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: 25.112-b15 (Oracle Corporation)

Comment: You have set the packaging to type `pom`, but you're trying to build a jar file. I'm a little surprised that you have a jar file at all...

Comment: Just confirming that the pom.xml that you have shown generates no output (unless the parent pom is doing something funky, in which case you need to show it). It does not even create a `target` directory.

Comment: As already mentioned by @SteveC you can't produce a jar file using this pom file.. The packaging must be `jar` instead otherwise you will not get a jar file at all...

Comment: well, I am getting a jar file with this pom.xml

Comment: The only way you could be getting any kind of jar with that pom.xml is if you used `mvn jar:jar` on the command line. Even that results in `[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!` and an empty jar.

Comment: I am executing it in eclipse, not in the command line, with the goal 'package'. The pom.xml is exactly what I have sent to you and I am still getting a jar file and no warnings. Looks like something we are missing here.